# Command line open window

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I used to connect to two external displays. and now I'm using only laptop screen. When I open command line, window doesn't open in laptop display and I have to use 'move' to drag it into laptop screen.

So, how to make cmd line open in current laptop window?

Comment: Are you opening cmd from Start > Run? Or a shortcut on your taskbar/desktop/start menu? Or right-click Start > Command Prompt?

Comment: Open from the folder

Comment: That doesn't help clarify. The window preferences/settings will be stored against the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Clear down the Window Position values in the shortcut properties, and/or untick 'Let system position window'.

[image]